# How do I get these fields to be ordered by the same way in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have two fields "Role Code Old Value" and "Role Code New Value" both of these fields as you can see in the screenshot have the same values. The issue is that they are in a different order. What I want to do is have them in the same order because In my WHERE clause in SQL I have it set to where they shouldn't equal eachother and they technically do in this instance. How do I get both fields to order by the same?

Code:
Role Code Old Value:
=JOIN(LOOKUPSET(Fields!Account_Nbr.Value, Fields!Account_Nbr.Value, Fields!Role_Code_Old_Value.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")

Role Code New Value:
=JOIN(LOOKUPSET(Fields!Account_Nbr.Value, Fields!Account_Nbr.Value, Fields!Role_Code_Old_Value.Value, "DataSet1"), ", ")

[image]

Comment: Both expressions are identical, so you might want to edit your question and update this. However, I'm not sure you will be able to do this without either doing this in your dataset query or some custom code in your report. The custom route might be easier if you don't have much control of the data or if the data is coming from two datasets that cannot be joined for whatever reason. To do this in VB custom code you'll need to pass your result in, split it back up again, sort it and then reassemble before you compare.

Comment: Take a look at this for an example of code https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?545547-sorting-comma-delimited-strings